# Can you make a DataContract with a Single ValueType based Value?

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization, datacontract

I am curious if it is possible to create a DataContract that will serialize like so:

```
<MyCustomName>string value</MyCustomName>
```

OR

```
<MyCustomName>int</MyCustomName>
```

What I am ultimately trying to do is return a basic type with a Custom element name. I've tried the following:

```
[DataContract(Name = "MyCustomName")]
public class MyCustomName : String
{
}
```

But obviously you can't inherit a string or int value. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is an easier way but as far as I know the DataContractSerializer will respect it if your type implements [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx). So you could implement this interface and roll your own serialization of `MyCustomName`

Comment: That may be the case, but I am also trying to utilize the JSON automatic serialization and if I just do the IXmlSerializable I'll loose that functionality. You would think there would be an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning that type as a field in another class, then you could just use a surrogate property such as:

```
public TreeId Id { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "Id")]
private string IdSurrogate
{
    get
    {
        return Id.ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        Id = new TreeId(value);
    }
}
```

So instead of having to put DataContract on the TreeId class, the property IdSurrogate just handles translating it directly to a string value